# Trying to use C# to print a string that has a parameter while also testing if it exists

Tags: c#

```
string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "{0} exists.", curFile : "File does not exist.");
```

It came back with an error though.
What would be the correct way of writing this?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "{0} exists." : "File does not exist.", curFile);`

Comment: Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? $"{curFile} exists." : "File does not exist.");

Comment: is it just me or is this a very confusing way to do things?
Am i oldfashioned to think this wouldnt be worse if this took a few more lines?

Comment: @DenisSchaf depends how used to ternary you are, i suppose.. It doesn't perturb me much, in that I wouldn't take it out, but I agree with you in that probably wouldn't write it that way in the first place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is better i think:

```
string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? $"{curFile} exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) shows what is "$" doing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using string.Format syntax inside a ternary.

You can either supply the string.Format wrapper.

```
Console.WriteLine(
   File.Exists(curFile) 
     ? string.Format("{0} exists.", curFile) 
     : "File does not exist.");
```

Or go for string interpolation with a leading $ sign.

```
Console.WriteLine(
   File.Exists(curFile) 
    ? $"{curFile} exists." 
    : "File does not exist.");
```